# Drop Down List losing item styling when ajax post back occurs

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, ajax

On one of our pages, there is a drop down list that dynamically colors its items on pre-render. However, whenever there is an ajax postback by any of the controls on the page, it immediately loses all its styling (item colors). I can tell that the pre-render is getting called both when the page originally loads, and every time any ajax calls are made.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DeviceObjectDDL" runat="server" Style="width: 350px;" OnPreRender="ColorDeviceListItems" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DeviceObjectDDL_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

And

```
    protected void ColorDeviceListItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((DropDownList) sender).DataSource == null) return;
        var disabledList = ((List<Device>) ((DropDownList) sender).DataSource).FindAll(d => !d.Active || !d.Visible);

        foreach (var device in disabledList)
        {
            var item = ((DropDownList) sender).Items.FindByValue(device.ID.ToString());
            if (item == null) continue;
            if ((!device.Active) && (!device.Visible))
                item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "Purple");
            else
            {
                if (!device.Active)
                    item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "Blue");
                if (!device.Visible)
                    item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "#8B0000");
            }
        }
    }
```

When the `ColorDeviceListItems` method is called during ajax requests, the `sender` datasource is null, so it simply returns.

Comment: Put a break point in your OnSelectedIndexChanged event handler, it might be possible that it is firing and potentially removing the styling?

Comment: Nope, nothing there is firing.

Comment: I think I was able to answer it, see below... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

Instead of using the `PreRender` event, use the `DataBound` event instead -- this should ensure that the event is fired after the data source has been re-materialized by the view state.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DeviceObjectDDL" runat="server" Style="width: 350px;" OnDataBound="ColorDeviceListItems" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DeviceObjectDDL_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

**Step 2**

Rather than using the sender, which could be anything that caused the post-back to occur.  Use the identifier of the control itself, i.e.; `DeviceObjectDDL` instead.  It is already correctly marked with `runat="server"` which should allow you to directly access it in the code behind.

```
protected void ColorDeviceListItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceObjectDDL.DataSource == null) return;
    var disabledList = ((List<Device>)(DeviceObjectDDL.DataSource).FindAll(d => !d.Active || !d.Visible);

    foreach (var device in disabledList)
    {
        var item = DeviceObjectDDL.Items.FindByValue(device.ID.ToString());
        if (item == null) continue;
        if ((!device.Active) && (!device.Visible))
            item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "Purple");
        else
        {
            if (!device.Active)
                item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "Blue");
            if (!device.Visible)
                item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "#8B0000");
        }
    }
}
```

Relying on the sender is not the best practice in this specific situation as there is no guarantee that the sender is the desired control.  And this is evident with AJAX calls...

Comment: Even more odd, `DataSource` is still showing up null on the ajax postback. On the original load, all is fine, but the postback is giving me fits.

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled?

Comment: Check this out, it sounds like they had a similar situation in which they solved by not using `PreRender`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578846/dropdownlist-empty-after-postback

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't allow it to persist, even when it's set to the `OnDataBound` method instead. It appears that when there is a postback it does a near refresh of the page. The `DeviceObjectDDL` HTML is reinitialized but on the back end, it's never rebound. So it displays the data, just not the formatting.

Comment: It is a dropdownlist, do I am assuming the amount of data is small.  Just re-query the data and assign the `DataSource`.

Comment: There are about 120 different items on the page that can cause a postback, that could get a bit extensive. Especially since plenty of things don't trigger the prerender event. The only thing I could possibly think of doing would be to make a persistent session variable that reloads the data on every prerender.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96817/discussion-between-david-pine-and-jdsfighter).